# why use a private repository like GitHub?

Tags: github

Would you use a private repository unless more developers are working on the same project from different locations? What can services such as GitHub offer instead of Microsoft Teamviewer for keepeng track of the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I move around a lot, so I find it pretty handy to keep my repository on the cloud. If you do ever find yourself having to integrate more members located in different places into your team, having something like github makes it much easier.